# Infinispan distributed cache and executing tasks on primary key owner

Tags: infinispan

Is it possible to get Infinispan (9.4+) to execute a task on a primary key owner?  Like if I give it a cache, a key in that cache, and a Runnable/Callable, can it just execute that task on the owner of that key?

This would be similar to Hazelcast IExecutorService's submitToKeyOwner or executeOnKeyOwner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways.

The simplest if the key exists is just to use DistributedStreams

`cache.entrySet().stream().filterKeys(Collections.singleton(key)).forEach((cache, k) -> <do stuff>);`

If the key doesn't exist you can use the ClusterExecutor

`cacheManager.executor().singleNodeSubmission().filterTargets(Collections.singleton(address)
   .submit(<runnable>);`

You can find the target address by invoking

`Address address = cache.getAdvancedCache().getDistributionManager()
   .getCacheTopology().getDistributionInfo(key).primary();`

I also suggest you check out this section http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#execute_code_grid

Comment: Also to note you can use DistributedExecutor, however this is deprecated and will eventually be removed.

Comment: I think I had your second suggestion figured out but I really like the first one using streams.  I hadn't considered that.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Also to note that the forEach method on distributed streams runs in an at least once delivery mode. Not sure if that is problematic or not. You can make it run in at most once mode by disabling rehash awareness. http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#rehash_aware

Comment: It's definitely something I need to be aware of.  I'm assuming that's only an issue on an unstable cluster (e.g. member just left/degraded or member joining).

Comment: Correct, if the cluster is stable it will guarantee exactly once semantics.